# Python Selenium: Loop webpage until element is found

Tags: python, loops, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to write an automation test that will go to a specific webpage, click a link inside and stay in the next page. That next page will not always show (sometimes it will show a connection error), so I'm making it find a specific element (that is suppossed to be in the page I'm looking for) and if the element is found, it stays there, if not, then go back to the beginning of the script (making a loop). I can make it go to the page and click the link, but when the connection error happens it just stays there and won't go back. I'm pretty new in python and selenium so there are probably some things I still not fully understand, but I'm learning with practice. I'm stuck here:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

def driver_init():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:#the path')
    driver.get('#the webpage')
    element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="conten"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/a')
    element.click()
    elt = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="logint"]/div/a/img')
    elt = True

driver_init()
while elt = False:
    driver_init()
```

How can I make it repeat the script if the element is not shown? or how to make it repeat the script if the connection error happens? It's not refreshing the page, it's going back to the beginning, I've tried many things but none helped me, so there may be some text left from those tries. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing is needing to do a condition on a result after page load.  Selenium Waiting for an element, will pass or fail, but in my experience, doesn't allow conditional logic to wrap around it. Once it fails to find the element, the test ends. Beyond your example, a case could happen with A/B testing, where 30% of the time a different page loads and you want to divert the test based on different outcomes of what loads.

What you can do create a method holding your main test automation, and a secondary method to handle the waiting or restarting your test.  This secondary method uses regex to look for an item in the page source.  Regex can have a condition built around it without prematurely ending the test. Here's an example:

```
import re # Importing the RegEx library

def your_test(driver):
     # your selenium test code up to when you need to wait
     # I'm passing the defined webdriver along with the text I'm looking for in the page source.
     find_or_restart(driver, "Thank You!") 
     # your test code after something is found found on page....

def find_or_restart(driver, text):
     src = driver.page_source # loading page source
     text_found = re.search(r'%s' % (text), src) # regex looking for text
     print("checking for text on page...")
     if text_found:
         return
     else:
         print("not found. restart test...")
         your_test(driver)
```

The connection error should be investigated.

Another aspect to this would be an infinite loop if the fail case happens 100% of the time.  You can add a counter, as a global variable, that increments each time the else condition is triggered.  Then in the find_or_restart method, you check the value of the counter, and if it's greater than a specified amount, you end the test as a fail.

Sometimes the QA community will argue that such a test, like working around a connection error, is not a valid work around.  Instead they will suggest the tester should let it fail so someone can fix the issue you're attempting to work around).  That's probably the best practice in general,  however, in some cases you might be testing with 3rd parties that you can't control their uptime.  Sometimes workarounds are required.  Examples for this abound in Telecom (automating a phone call that traverses multiple carriers), or in building bots for games, etc.  Anyway, I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

First of all you should use [selenium wait](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) to wait for element to be present.
Repeating part of code on fail is not a common practice. Why this page is not always loaded properly?

Comment: I tried the selenium wait but it didn't make a difference, or just gave me syntax error, I'm trying again with it and the other answer. This webpage gives me an appointment for some documents I need to do but it hardly ever works (since there is a limit of appointments it gives per month), I need to keep doing this manually until it works (showing the page I need) and there's no way to know when it'll work, I'm trying to automate it so I don't keep wasting hours just clicking and reloading. And since I'm new in this I think it's a good practice too.

Answer (score -2):

I am not going to code here. I am giving you the solution written and want yourself to code it.

---

Step 1: create two methods 1st initializes the webdriver. 2nd kills the webdriver

---

Step 2: Declare FLAG as false and once you initialize web driver and invoke chrome, perform your activity of finding a particular element using WEBDRIVER WAIT. 
 If found, proceed to next step and set FLAG to true.

---

Step 3: If FLAG is still false, call the KILL WEBDRIVER method, then call the driver_init(): method

---

Comment: I tried this for a few hours, I think I get everything fine except that I'm pretty confused about the FLAG part, what exactly do you mean by FLAG? I'm getting syntax error trying the if statement too but I believe it has to do with the FLAG part I don't understand yet. Thanks for the help

Comment: FLAG is just a variable i usually use. a Boolean variable to be declared which will accept either true/false. 
DECLARE FLAG AS FALSE meaning: set the Boolean variable FLAG to FALSE initially.